# Get open outlook email as MailItem in Windows service

Tags: c#, service, outlook

In case of a desktop application, if I execute the following code lines to open an email and then get the related MailItem everything works fine:

```
 string file = @"C:\TestEML\EmlMail.eml";
 System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(file);
 Outlook.Application oApp = (Outlook.Application)Marshal.GetActiveObject("Outlook.Application");
 Outlook.MailItem oItem = (Outlook.MailItem)oApp.ActiveInspector().CurrentItem; // now oItem is the COM object that represents our .eml file
```

But what about in case of Windows service? The previous code does not work as oApp.ActiveInspector() returns NULL... no window (inspector) is open.

So the question is: how to link a MailItem instance to the current open email in a Windows service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact is that **Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.**

If you are building a solution that runs in a server-side context, you should try to use components that have been made safe for unattended execution. Or, you should try to find alternatives that allow at least part of the code to run client-side. If you use an Office application from a server-side solution, the application will lack many of the necessary capabilities to run successfully. Additionally, you will be taking risks with the stability of your overall solution.

You can read more about that in the [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/257757) article.

Consider using a low-level API instead - Extended MAPI which allows to run the code from a Windows service or any other third-party wrappers around that API (for example, Redemption).

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of a Windows service is to have your code run when no user is logged in. But if you are trying to access a message currently open in Outlook, why do you even need to run as a service? Move your code to a COM addin, it will run every time Outlook runs.